# Using selenium to solve captcha

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, captcha, simplecaptcha

My Code below is keep solving a different Captcha ! Please correct my mistake as i don't know what's causing that!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from python3_anticaptcha import ImageToTextTask, CallbackClient
import time
import requests

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'https://urlmased.com/'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
username = browser.find_element_by_id("masked")
username.send_keys("testuser")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("masked")
password.send_keys("testpass")

image_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="masked"]').get_attribute('src')
pic = requests.get(image_link)
if pic.status_code == 200:
    with open("image.png", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pic.content)
ANTICAPTCHA_KEY = 'masked'
captcha_file = "image.png"
result = ImageToTextTask.ImageToTextTask(
    anticaptcha_key=ANTICAPTCHA_KEY).captcha_handler(captcha_file=captcha_file)

captcha = browser.find_element_by_id("masked")
captcha.send_keys(result['solution']['text'])
login = browser.find_element_by_id("yw2")
```

> Be Informed that the API is active so you can use it till you reach a solution. and then i will change it.
>
> Also the accuracy of solving is 100%

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202864/discussion-on-question-by-anna-plym-using-selenium-to-solve-captcha).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that the captcha URL in the page source is not an
actual image URL. It's a script to dynamically generate captcha
images there for when you use the captcha solver API you are solving a
defferent image than the browser loaded. To solve this we have to
save the same image the browser loaded. I traced the image request
and found out, it's using unique cookies that was generated when the
browser loaded the page.

Using Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from python3_anticaptcha import ImageToTextTask, CallbackClient
from time import sleep
import requests



def GetImageCookies():
    print('Extracting Browser Cookies')
    image_cookies = ''
    for cookie in browser.get_cookies():
        if cookie['name'] == 'ssc':
            image_cookies += 'ssc={};'.format(cookie['value'])
        elif cookie['name'] == 'ghsdfkjlksssalk35bbr':
            image_cookies += 'ghsdfkjlksssalk35bbr={};'.format(cookie['value'])
    # print(image_cookies)
    return image_cookies

def SaveImage(captcha_file = "master.jpg"):
    print('Saving the captcha image')
    header = {
    'Accept': 'image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en,en-US;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8',
    'Cookie': GetImageCookies(),
    'Host': 'masked',
    'Referer': 'masked',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'no-cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'}


    pic = requests.get('https://masked/site/captcha/v/',verify=False,headers = header)
    if pic.status_code == 200:
        with open(captcha_file, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(pic.content)

def SolveCapcha(captcha_file = "master.jpg"):
    print('Solving the captcha image')
    ANTICAPTCHA_KEY = 'masked'  
    result = ImageToTextTask.ImageToTextTask(
        anticaptcha_key=ANTICAPTCHA_KEY).captcha_handler(captcha_file=captcha_file)
    captcha_text = result['solution']['text']
    print('Captcha text is :',captcha_text)
    return captcha_text


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://masked/'
browser.get(url)
def Login():
    SaveImage()
    sleep(5)
    username = browser.find_element_by_id("masked_username")
    username.clear()
    username.send_keys("testuser")
    password = browser.find_element_by_id("masked")
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys("testpass")
    captcha = browser.find_element_by_id("masked")
    captcha.clear()
    captcha_text = SolveCapcha()
    captcha.send_keys(captcha_text)
    login = browser.find_element_by_id("masked").click()
    sleep(5)
    err_message = browser.find_elements_by_id('masked')
    if err_message :
        if err_message[0].text == 'The verification code is incorrect.':
            print(err_message[0].text)
            return False
    return True


"""The logic here is that the image gets downloaded using the cookies but sometimes
the letters are hard to be solved so each time we download the same image with the
same cookies the content of the image will be the same but how it's written is different
So we keep trying till we get it right """
while Login() == False:
    Login()
```

Using Requests and Beautiful soup:
the following is the idea not sure if it's working you will have to test yourself:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def SaveImage(captcha_file = "master.jpg"):
    print('Saving the captcha image')
    header = {
    'Accept': 'image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en,en-US;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8',
    'Host': 'masked',
    'Referer': 'https://masked/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'no-cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'}


    pic = session.get('https://masked/site/captcha/v/',verify=False,headers = header)
    if pic.status_code == 200:
        with open(captcha_file, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(pic.content)

with requests.Session() as session:
    source      = session.get(url = 'https://masked/',verify=False) # To get the itial cookies  
    soup        = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')  
    token       = soup.find('input', {'name': 'masked'}).get('value')
    SaveImage()
    captcha_text = SolveCapcha()
    post_data={"masked": token,
                'masked[username]': 'testuser',
                'masked[password]': 'testpass',
                'masked[captcha]': captcha_text,
                'masked':''}
    session.post('https://masked/', data=post_data,verify=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @pguradiario mentioned request.Session doesn't do anything.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from python3_anticaptcha import ImageToTextTask
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://masked/'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
username = browser.find_element_by_id("masked")
username.send_keys("testuser")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("masked")
password.send_keys("testpass")

image_link = url + browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="masked"]').get_attribute('src')
print(image_link)

ANTICAPTCHA_KEY = "masked"
user_answer = ImageToTextTask.ImageToTextTask(anticaptcha_key=ANTICAPTCHA_KEY).\
    captcha_handler(captcha_link=image_link)

captcha = browser.find_element_by_id("masked")
captcha.send_keys(user_answer['solution']['text'])
login = browser.find_element_by_id("masked")
```

Comment: 'src' gives the absolute URL, which needs to be concatenated with base URL. I'm taking the captcha on the page and sending it to captha_handler.

Answer (score 0):

Captcha screenshot instead of getting image from the link should solve the issue.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from python3_anticaptcha import ImageToTextTask
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'https://urlmased.com/'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
username = browser.find_element_by_id("masked")
username.send_keys("testuser")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("masked")
password.send_keys("testpass")

captcha = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="masked"]')
captcha_image = captcha.screenshot_as_png
with open('image.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(captcha_image)
ANTICAPTCHA_KEY = 'masked'
captcha_file = "image.png"
result = ImageToTextTask.ImageToTextTask(
    anticaptcha_key=ANTICAPTCHA_KEY).captcha_handler(captcha_file=captcha_file)

captcha = browser.find_element_by_id("masked")
captcha.send_keys(result['solution']['text'])
login = browser.find_element_by_id("yw2")
```